# Searchbar from JSON data with Ionic 3

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm very new to Ionic 3 and I'm trying to filter trough a json response with Ionic 3 search bar. Anyone can help?

This is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PublikasiProvider} from '../../providers/publikasi/publikasi';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-publikasi',
  templateUrl: 'publikasi.html'
})
export class PublikasiPage {
  private publikasi: any;
  private errorMessage: string;
  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public publikasiProvider: PublikasiProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getPublikasi();
  }

  getPublikasi(){
    this.publikasiProvider.getPublikasi()
        .subscribe(
          publikasi =>this.publikasi = publikasi,
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    this.getPublikasi();
    let val = ev.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.publikasi = this.publikasi.filter((item) => {
        return (item.storeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
      }
    }
}
```

And the Markup:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

    <ion-list>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let p of publikasi">
            <h3>{{ p.judul_ind }} </h3>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

I get this error when I search:

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[{
    "judul_ind": "Distrik Batanta Utara Dalam Angka 2014",
    "file_cover": "Distrik-Batanta-Utara-Dalam-Angka-2014.jpg",
    "file_pdf": "Distrik-Batanta-Utara-Dalam-Angka-2014.pdf"
  }]
```

Comment: where is `storeName` here?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your publikasi to:

```
private publikasi: string[];
```

and add:

```
public filteredPublikasi: string[];
```

Then replace

```
publikasi =>this.publikasi = publikasi
```

with

```
(publikasi) => {
    for(var property in publikasi) {
        this.publikasi.push(publikasi[property]);
    }
    this.filteredPublikasi = this.publikasi;
}
```

Your filter logic will be something like:

```
this.filteredPublikasi = this.publikasi.filter((item) => {
    return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
```

Replace the *ngFor with `filteredPublikasi` instead of `publikasi`. The reason we added this `filteredPublikasi` is for us to keep all the data returned by `publikasiProvider.getPublikasi()`.